# How to specify grid in terms of cells, not distances?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Is it possible to specify a grid in terms of number of grid lines, rather than as spacing (in PowerPoint 2016)? I want to have a 2x3 grid to help me design my presentation, but can only find a way to specify the grid in terms of distance between lines.

The settings I have found:
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with inserting a 2*3 table and using that? [Add a table to a slide - PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-table-to-a-slide-34f106c9-5320-4b89-9129-806e64b258ac)

Comment: Is there a way to make it unselectable? And having it not show up in the final presentation would also be nice.

Comment: I don't know about unselectable, but you can delete table borders.

Comment: If you put the table on the slide's layout (View | Slide Master, insert the table there), it won't be selectable on the slide.  You can also turn on Guides, then Ctrl+Drag the default guides to create additional ones. Older versions of PPT only allowed you to create up to 8 vertical and 8 horizontal guides. That limitation's been lifted since at least PPT 2010.

Comment: That is a good option

Comment: By the way, in PPT 2013 (I think) and 2016, you can create/move/delete guides with a bit of VBA; if you need to create the same "grid" of guides repeatedly, that could save a lot of time and add to the accuracy of the thing. If that's of interest, let me know and I'll cobble up some example code.

Comment: It would be very nice. I am a complete novice at VBA, so I probably wouldn't be able to do it on my own :) help on how to use it would be appreciated as well.

Comment: @TokeFaurby See examples below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code example from a page on the PowerPoint FAQ site that I maintain:

Working with Guides in PPT 2013 and later
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01214-Working-with-Guides-in-PPT-2013-and-later.htm

If you're not accustomed to working with VBA, there's a link to a simple tutorial at the bottom of that page.

This lets you add horiz/vert guides pretty much wherever you like:

```
Sub AddGuides()

    Dim HGuides As String
    Dim VGuides As String
    Dim x As Long
    Dim aGuideArray() As String

    ' Edit these to indicate where you'd like to put guides:
    ' Values are in points, 72 points to the inch
    ' Separate each value from the next with a pipe | character

    ' Horizontal guide positions:
    HGuides = "72|144|256.5"
    ' Vertical guide positions:
    VGuides = "10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80|90|100"

    With ActivePresentation
        ' nb ppHorizonatalGuide = 1; ppVerticalGuide = 2
        ' nb to add guides to master rather than slides,
        '   use .SlideMaster.Guides.Add below
        '   in place of .Guides.Add

        ' First add the horizontal guides
        aGuideArray = Split(HGuides, "|")
        For x = LBound(aGuideArray) To UBound(aGuideArray)
            .Guides.Add ppHorizontalGuide, CSng(aGuideArray(x))
        Next

        ' and now the vertical guides
        aGuideArray = Split(VGuides, "|")
        For x = LBound(aGuideArray) To UBound(aGuideArray)
            .Guides.Add ppVerticalGuide, CSng(aGuideArray(x))
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong (very likely) but I followed your guide to the best of my ability, and get an error: `Run-time error '424' Object required`. Debugging points to the line `Guides.Add ppHorizontalGuide, CSng(aGuideArray(x))`

Comment: @TokeFaurby Apologies ... somehow in copy/pasting from VBA into the answer here, I lost a dot.  The problem line should start with .Guides.Add ... etc.  I'll edit the answer above to fix it.  Thanks for testing/catching that.

Comment: For reference the `VGuides` and `HGuides` specify the positions of the guidelines in pixels?

Comment: @TokeFaurby No. Like most measurements in PowerPoint VBA, these are in points (72 points to the inch). Pixels wouldn't make a lot of sense: imagine what happens if you moved the presentation to a different PC with higher/lower video resolution.  Or just changed the zoom level on the current PC. All of your pixel measurements would go out the window. Um. Or Mac.